# Android: "java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android" While loading bitmaps from sdcard?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, bitmap

In my application  I have to display an image which is about 10000 x 5000 , using small images of 500x500 px. I.e;thru  tiling images.
In order to tile all images to one initially am collecting all bitmaps from sdcard in order to draw on canvas.

But while am loading images from extenal storage using   `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path)` i encounterd with error **java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android**

can any one how to avoid this error and gimme an idea how to tile lot of images in to a single image .

Thanking you,
Srinivas

Comment: Did you ever tried searching [OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=OutOfMemoryError%3A+bitmap+size+exceeds+VM+budget)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Never load any tiles that you don't need. "am collecting all bitmaps from sdcard" suggests that you are decompressing every image you might ever need, which would be the wrong approach.
2. Use smaller tiles. 256x256 is a good size.
3. Load them as Config.RGB565 (i.e. 16bpp).
4. Regularly recycle() Bitmaps you don't need.

Basically you need to implement some sort of most-recently-used (MRU) Bitmap cache.

Comment: But can u brief it what exactly i need to do ? Actually i need to to tile all image to single image like google map .When am zooming i need to use another set of images based on zoom factor . can u please tell how to accomplish this task . I never did this kind of tasks .

Comment: Bitmaps that are decompressed take up *lots* of memory. You should only decompress the ones you *actually need* at any one time.

Comment: am creating custom view extending view class. In draw method how to update new bitmaps when view scrolled horzontally and vertically.

Comment: You basically need two sets of data: One grid of images for the entire dataset, and another grid of images currently displaying in the viewport. When the user scrolls the view, you update the second grid, then rerender the view.

Comment: ok thank u .. I will try like this.am new to this kind of things. But i need help.

Comment: it taking time to load from sdcard every time . Its not scrolling smoothly.

Comment: Yes, that'll be because loading anything from flash-based storage is intrinsically slow. If you know what tiles you are going to need (or may need) in advance of them being displayed, you should pre-load them.

Comment: if i preload bitmaps from sdcard am getting out of memory error .

Comment: In case you hadn't noticed, the art of programming usually boils down to working out the best way around the unfortunate twin realities of not having infinite memory or instantaneous I/O.

Comment: Here's what you do. You *only* load the bitmaps you actually need, or know you will need very shortly. Keep track of how many bitmaps you have loaded at any one time and how much memory they take up decompressed. If decompressing a bitmap pushes you past a certain threshold (say 2MB or 4MB) then you immediately recycle the least-recently-used bitmap.

Comment: Secondly, you load the bitmaps on worker threads, i.e. AsyncTasks. Never do heavy I/O on the main thread. Keeping your I/O on background threads will keep your UI smooth and responsive, even if a bitmap or two is momentarily missing (the canonical example being Google Maps).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Exactyly what i want i have a grid of images at every zoomlevel , i need to update  tose images when am zooming it was like google maps.

Comment: "ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(23074): 524288-byte external allocation too large  for this process." Can you what is the meaning of this exception.

Comment: It means your heap cannot satisfy a request for a contiguous 512KB of RAM. I assume this is just *one* of your bitmaps... you are asking for the same amount of RAM as a 256x512 32bpp image would take. That's too much to do safely. Use smaller tiles, use 16bpp. A 256x256 16bpp image will occupy 128KB. You should be able to load at good few of those (30? 40?) before hitting heap limits.

Comment: actual all my images are 500 x 500 am getting those from server and then i have to arrange them as a chart. You said apply Least recently used bitmap policy. can u gimme any idea how to do this task ? as u said am loading images using asynctask then invaliding draw calls. its fine but how to recycle my bitmaps . How do i get least used bitmaps. ?

Comment: Please help me in this case . Am struggling from many days. Really thank ful to u.

Comment: Most *screens* are smaller than 500x500! Why are you need such massive images?? How many pixels do they *actually* *need* to be? Maybe you should use BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize to scale them down. And why aren't you at least ensuring they are 16-bit? Finally, re "least-recently used" bitmaps, you put *every* bitmap you load *on a list*. An ArrayList or something. At the same time you track how much memory you are using. If the memory usage gets too high - its up to you to define what "too high" is - then recycle the last bitmap on the list and System.gc() for luck.

Comment: This application is developing for tablets i.e; samsung galaxy tab