# android java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, sdk

i've some leaks problems. 
What i'm doing is loading some pictures in a table. I've created an asyncronous class for loading images.

In my table while i'm cycling the array I add my class

```
final LoaderImageView image = new LoaderImageView(getContext(),vgood[i].getImageUrl(),(int)(ratio *80),(int)(ratio *80));
row.addView(image);
```

In my asyncronous class i'm loading images from this

```
return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), "name");
```

Called by

```
public void setImageDrawable(final String imageUrl) {
    mDrawable = null;
    mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                mDrawable = getDrawableFromUrl(imageUrl);
                imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(COMPLETE);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(FAILED);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(FAILED);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }.start();
}
```

When i've a lot of images to load the app crashes due to out of memory caused by this line

```
return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), "name");
```

How can i fix that? where i'm going wrong?

thank you

Comment: are you sure they're not just *too many* images?

Comment: mmm.. it could be possible, there's a limit about that?

Comment: if I remember, heap memory is 16MB on phones (and as a default on the emulator). Anyway, there's a lot of questions here about this error, so be sure to check them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Never load any tiles that you don't need. "am collecting all bitmaps from sdcard" suggests that you are decompressing every image you might ever need, which would be the wrong approach.
2. Use smaller tiles. 256x256 is a good size.
3. Load them as Config.RGB565 (i.e. 16bpp).
4. Regularly recycle() Bitmaps you don't need.

Basically you need to implement some sort of most-recently-used (MRU) Bitmap cache

Extrated From

[Android: "java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android" While loading bitmaps from sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990761/android-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android-whil)